# How to mock react 'dispatch' function from useContext() in a react component using Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a `dispatch` event has been fired from a button in my component. The `dispatch` is coming from `useContent()`. But I get the error `dispatch is not a function`. Can anyone help/point me in the right direction?

```
import LoanListItem from './LoanListItem';
import LoansContext from './loansContext';

it('should dispatch an action on clicking button', () => {
        const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
        const TestComponent = () => (
            <LoansContext value={mockDispatch}>
                <LoanListItem {...mockProps} />
            </LoansContext>
        );
        
        const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent />);
        wrapper.find(LoanListItem).dive().find('.button').simulate('click');
        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            type: 'selectedLoan',
            payload: 1,
        });
    });
```

And a stripped down version of the component to test.

```
const LoanListItem = (props) => {
    const { id, title } = props.loan;
    const dispatch = useContext(LoansContext);

    const clickHandler = () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'selectedLoan', payload: id });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Invest</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: What is the LoansContext file content ? I think your TestComponent should be wrapped wich LoansContext.Provider

Comment: ```import React from 'react';

const LoansContext = React.createContext(null);

export default LoansContext;``` and in my App the component is wrapped in `<LoansContext.Provider value={dispatch}>< LoanListItem value={dispatch}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your TestComponent is not using the Provider, you should fix it like this:

```
const TestComponent = () => (
    <LoansContext.Provider value={mockDispatch}>
        <LoanListItem {...mockProps} />
    </LoansContext.Provider>
);
```

You should also not using shallow as it won't traverse through components, replace it with mount.

Comment: Thanks, for spotting that! But still getting error `TypeError: dispatch is not a function` [Jest 62,1]. Currently using React 17.0.1 and Enzyme 3.11.0 with "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.3.1".

Comment: Adding mount instead of shallow seems to work, although its now complaining about `wrapper.dive` is not a function - I thought I had to use `dive` to gain access to my component within the `LoansContect.Provider`?

Comment: Didn't know about dive.. I think you can remove that part and it should work as mount render the whole tree

Comment: Excellent! removing `.dive()` worked! - thanks very much for your help Axnff! :-)